# S3 tagging and access control policies not working for limiting the tags keyset on an object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

Trying to restrict tags to only a given set of keys that can be attached to the objects. Using bucket level policies to define this condition. However, the logic is not working. Bucket policy (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/tagging-and-policies.html)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<Account-Id>:user/AdminUser"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObjectTagging",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-notifications-per-prefix/*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                    "s3:RequestObjectTagKeys": "LIFE"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Boto3 code to upload the object

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3.put_object_tagging(
    Bucket='test-notifications-per-prefix',
    Key="file.txt",
    Tagging = {
        'TagSet': [
            {
                'Key': "TEST",
                'Value': "SHORTTERM"
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

The object is still getting uploaded when i run the above code.

**I am not able to figure out as why this is happening. Tried denying object tagging in the bucket policy (removed the condition from the policy and made the effect as Deny) then any object uploaded with a tag was throwing an access denied error. (so, the rules are being applied for sure)**

Can you please let me know as what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: As I understand the condition part locks correct. Have you tried to set the principal to '*' to see if that works than you run your lambda? I don't know what entity the lambda have then you run it.

Comment: @ErikAsplund as per my understanding, the condition part checks whether the request that is coming from the given principal is satisfying the conditions. If yes, then they apply the check. If it is Deny, then they do not all the operation from happening. If it is an allow, they check the other conditions. I found the solution though of restricting the key value pairs. I will post the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:user/AdminUser"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObjectTagging",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/prefix1/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:RequestObjectTag/LIFE": [
                        "2",
                        "15"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Able to restrict the key and value pairs in my S3 bucket using the following bucket policy. An explicit deny is denying all the requests coming from the principal that do not have the following tags.

**However, this policy will not work for object that are uploaded without tags.**

EDIT:

We can define the below policy defined for a role to enforce the tags that are uploaded with given key and value pairs

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/prefix1/*",
        "Condition": {
            "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                "s3:RequestObjectTagKeys": "LIFE"
            },
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "s3:RequestObjectTag/LIFE": ["2", "15"]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}